# Is there any way I can rate songs in iTunes using java?

Tags: java, itunes

I have a list of songs rated by folder they are in (e.g. 1 star songs in a folder, 2 star songs in another folder and so on). I want to rate songs in iTunes depending on which folder they are in, fast and automatically using codes from java.

Answer (score 1):

I found a perl script that does similar thing: http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=38083

It would make it event simpler to use folder name instead of tags to set rating.

If you want to do similar thing in java, you'd have to use [Jacob](http://danadler.com/jacob/) (example [here](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/java/itunes-com-with-java-and-swing)) or [BridJ](http://code.google.com/p/bridj/) to do access iTunes database via COM. It's painful, platform-dependant and I wouldn't recommend doing it unless you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes stores its library as an XML file so I suppose you could manipulate that directly from within Java.  Of course you'd have to be careful with this approach as different versions of iTunes have different XML formats, and if you invalidate the library than all the metadata iTunes is holding about the tracks in its library will be lost.